# Hibernate open-close SessionFactory on every query vs on app instance

Tags: java, mysql, swing, hibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am currently working on a Java Swing application in NetBeans with Hibernate guided with this [wonderful repo from GitHub](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate).

From the example code found [here](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate/blob/master/fluent-hibernate-examples/src/main/java/com/github/fluent/hibernate/example/mysql/MySqlExample.java), it basically urges new programmers to open and close SessionFactory connection every time certain queries have been executed:

```
try {
    HibernateSessionFactory.Builder.configureFromDefaultHibernateCfgXml()
            .createSessionFactory();
    new MySqlExample().doSomeDatabaseStuff();
} catch (Throwable th) {
    th.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    HibernateSessionFactory.closeSessionFactory();
}

private void doSomeDatabaseStuff() {
    deleteAllUsers();
    insertUsers();
    countUsers();
    User user = findUser(USER_LOGIN_A);
    LOG.info("User A: " + user);
}
```

Is this a good programming exercise? Isn't it more efficient to open the SessionFactory on app startup and close it on `WindowClosing event`? What are the drawbacks of each method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using a persistent connection means you are going to have as many opened connections on your database as opened clients, plus you'll have to make sure it stays open (very often it will be closed if it stays idle for a long time).

On the other hand, executing a query will be significantly faster if the connection is already opened.

So it really depends on often your clients will use the database. If they use it very rarely, a persistent connection is useless.